# How to write for pure mono for Android?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I understand how to write to Xamarin.Android. You download the installer, it installs everything, including mono for Visual Studio, etc. Then you select Android application in the new project menu.

But what if I told you, that I wanted to write to pure MonoDroid and not to Xamarin.Android? After all, monodroid is open-source and free right? How do I write to it without xamarin?

Perhaps some tiny tutorial please?

Answer (score 3):

> monodroid is open-source and free right?

No.  Mono for Android was the original name of Xamarin Android.  It is not an open source product, it is owned by Xamarin.